# Is "minus your points" a valid phrase?

Tags: parts-of-speech, is-it-a-word

Suppose that a teacher says

> I will minus your points if you cheat.

To mean "I will deduct your points."
Here, *minus* is apparently used as a verb.
Checking out the [dictionaries](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/minus),
it can be seen that *minus* is only listed
as a preposition, adjective, and/or noun.
However, some people argue that "minus your points" is a phrase
commonly used.
Therefore, I ask this question here to double-check
that it is invalid to use "minus" as a verb.

Is this phrase acceptable?
If so, is it commonly used?

Comment: It's not common in most of the US.

Comment: Not common in most dialects.  Do not use this yourself.  But if someone else uses it, do not correct them.  (Unless they have asked you to correct their English.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an unfortunate but not an uncommon use of the word. In environments where math is done and spoken of casually such corruptions are not unusual. They should have some of their points minused themselves.

Comment: You are free not to use it if you don't like it.  But your value judgments are of no greater value than those of people who do use it.

Comment: We are all free to misuse the English language as we please. That keeps the problems coming. My lighthearted comments reflect my disappointment with those who should know better, such as the proctor of the test in the OP's remarks.

Comment: And I'm disputing your "should know better". (I don't believe I've ever come across the usage, by the way. But then I also don't remember coming across "proctor" used in the way you have just done so.)